# Mostrar una variable de un archivo JS a otro archivo JS

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, twitter-api, http-get

Estoy programando un `BOT` de Twitter simple en `NodeJS` y necesito mostrar variables y datos externos y mostrarlos en mi archivo `main` llamado `bot.js` (más abajo está lo que contiene).

Tengo un archivo llamado `botele.js` el cual es donde se encuentra la variable externa a mostrar en mi `main`, el cual tiene este código:

```
var unirest = require("unirest");
var req = unirest("GET", "https://xxxx");

req.headers({
    "x-rapidapi-host": "xx",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "xxx"
});


req.end(function (res) {
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);

    console.log(res.body);
});
```

la respuesta obtenida es esta:

```js
{
  results: [ { id: 244, idSeason: 436, name: 'Regular Season' } ],
  page: 1,
  itemsPerPage: 20
}
```

Y Luego tengo otro archivo JS llamado `bot.js` el cual se encarga de publicar el *twit*, donde:

```
const config = require('./config');
const datasport = require('./botele');
const twit = require('twit');
const T = new twit(config);

T.post(
    'statuses/update',
    { status: 'Prueba' },
    (err, data, response) => {
        console.log(err, data, response);
    }
);
```

Básicamente lo que deseo es mostrar la variable `name` generada por el archivo `botele.js` en mi archivo `main` `bot.js`, más exactamente en `status` del código `bot.js`.

¿Es esto posible?

Comment: Es decir quieres enviar el resultado de `res.body` por `T.post` ? No se entiende muy bien lo que quieres enviar y cual quieres exportar/importar

Comment: @EugeniBejan exactamente, necesito mostrar res.boy.mivariable por T.post, exactamente en el campo status:

Comment: @Bryan R mira la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución más sencilla es crear en un archivo la funciona que la llamaras solo cuando acabes la petición `http`.

Primero tendrías que envolver el código encargado de enviar los datos a twitter en una función.

Ejemplo:

```
const config = require('./config')
const datasport = require('./botele')
const twit = require('twit')
const T = new twit(config)

function enviar(payload){
    T.post(
        'statuses/update',
        { status: payload }, //JSON.strignify también te puede ser útil.
        (err, data, response) => {
          console.log(err, data, response);
        }
      )
}

//Exportas la función para poder usarla en otros archivos.
module.exports = {
    enviar
}
```

Después de esto, en otro archivo simplemente la puedes importar haciendo uso de `require`

```
var unirest = require("unirest");
var req = unirest("GET", "https://xxxx");
const {enviar} = require('./twit') //Importar la función que enviara los datos a twitter

req.headers({
    "x-rapidapi-host": "xx",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "xxx"
});


req.end(function (res) {
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);
    enviar(req.body) //O req.body.mivariable
    console.log(res.body);
});
```

Comment: me salta este error: TypeError: enviar is not a function